# Python Extract Access Token From Key Analytics Embed API

Tags: python, google-analytics

I haven't really used Python before but it's the only example Google gives you...

I have tested my JS/HTML code to display an Analytics dashboard to clients on our site using a temporary token from the [OAuth 2.0 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). Everything works fine, but of course the token only lasts an hour.

The Python script they give you to extract a key is:

```
# service-account.py

import json
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

# The scope for the OAuth2 request.
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'

# The location of the key file with the key data.
KEY_FILEPATH = 'path/to/json-key.json'

# Load the key file's private data.
with open(KEY_FILEPATH) as key_file:
  _key_data = json.load(key_file)

# Construct a credentials objects from the key data and OAuth2 scope.
_credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    _key_data['client_email'], _key_data['private_key'], SCOPE)

# Defines a method to get an access token from the credentials object.
# The access token is automatically refreshed if it has expired.
def get_access_token():
  return _credentials.get_access_token().access_token
```

I have changed the file path of the json key to the location of the file and I have installed the required python client for the Analytics API and have checked it's installed.

When I go to the python script in a browser I get an internal server error, which is understandable but how to I get the key into my HTML/PHP page? Or is there an alternative PHP script than can extract the key?

The code they give you for the front end (where the key is supposed to go) is:

```
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  /**
   * Authorize the user with an access token obtained server side.
   */
  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    'serverAuth': {
      'access_token': ' [ ACCESS TOKEN HERE] '
    }
});
```